# using C# with the Open XML SDK 2.5 how can you set a cell's value individual characters to specific individual font colours

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to colourise my amino acids 1 letter codes automatically from the c# from which they are currently output.

The spreadsheet is output correctly and I have a column such as this example:

```
A B
1 KJAGLKJGKASLJG
2 FLFSFHDSHDSHHF
3 KJSDALKDJKLFJK
4 KLFDJSHASDFFSD
```

Every distinct character will be assigned its own colour.  For example, K would be Red, L would be Yellow, and D would be Orange.  This must be done with the Open XML SDK and not Excel COM programming or a VBA script.

At the moment, this is how the cells are output, but they use the default style sheet.

```
string columnName = AlphabetLetterRollOver((int) columnIndex);
string cellRef = columnName + (rowIndex + 1);
Cell cell1 = new Cell {CellReference = cellRef, StyleIndex = 1U};
cell1.DataType = CellValues.String;
CellValue cellValue1 = new CellValue();
cellValue1.Text = columnValue;
cell1.Append(cellValue1);
row1.Append(cell1);
```

I tried the following code as a test case to achieve what I want, but it did not work; it throws an exception:

```
RunProperties runProperties = new RunProperties();
FontSize fontSize = new FontSize() {Val = 10D};
Color color = new Color() {Rgb = "FF000000"};
RunFont runFont = new RunFont() {Val = "Consolas"};
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily() {Val = 3};

runProperties.Append(fontSize);
runProperties.Append(color);
runProperties.Append(runFont);
runProperties.Append(fontFamily);

Run run = new Run();
Text text = new Text();
text.Text = "A";

run.Append(runProperties);
run.Append(text);

cell1.Append(run);
row1.Append(cell1);
```

This exception thrown is as follows:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperatioonException
Message: Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree.
Source: DocumentFormat.OpenXml
StrackTrace:    at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement.AppendChild[T](T newChild)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.Append(OpenXmlElement[] newChildren)
```

Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create `shared strings` with each letter set to color you need. Then append as many of them to cells you want.

EDIT -

Download  [OpenXMLSDKToolV25.msi](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

Now here is the trick, OpenXML productivity tool is the one you need here. It allows you to brows an existing Excel file and break it down to CODES : [watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSSMLR19JWA)

Now what you need to do is create an Excel sheet manually with what you want [In your case having multi colur text] Then open this Excel file with productivity tool and understand the CODE . Note that you will need to understand Spreadsheet file structure to understand this CODE [ Refer [this]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278328.aspx) .. Now write your codes to meet your requirement using codes of Productivity tool

NOTE - Once you analyse the dummy Spreadsheet with Productivity tool you will understand why giving or guiding with CODE examples as an answer is not practical. Just try with A cell with multicolor texts

Comment: I tried the productivity tool - however I haven't tried using SharedString objects instead of CellValue objects - I will try it and see, then I will get back to you to say if it worked or not.  Thanks!